# Interface Node class

Tags: java, nodes

```
public class Nodelmpl implements Node {

  private int data;
  private Node next;

  public Nodelmpl(int data) {
    this.data = data;
  }


  @Override
  public int getId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return data;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Node n) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.data == n.data.id();
  }


  public Node getNext() {
    return next;
  }


}
```

I'm trying to finish these two methods but im confuse on how to do the equals method and unsure if im doing the id command correctly and setting up the correct constructors.

More explanation:

I'm trying to make NodeImpl.java and this implementation takes into consideration the features in the interface. Then I finish these two methods no other new methods so Node only has two public methods – one for getting the
node, and one that overrides Object’s equal method. This method should check if two nodes share an id. If they do, return true, otherwise, return false. There is no setId method.

GOAL: I need to add the sufficient constructors and finish the methods in the implementation

Comment: Don't compare int with `equals`, use `==`. You should also try to explain more clearly what you are trying to do and what is the problem.

Comment: Okay thank you. I've wrote more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only way to set the `data` is via constructor you should create one which receives an int parameter

```
public Nodelmpl(int data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Two more comments:

`data` and `next` should be `private` and accessed via getters (or other 
methods)

Primitive types should be compared by `==`, not `equals`. The `equals` method 
should look like

```
public boolean equals(Node n) {
     return this.data == n.id();
}
```

Comment: n.data.id -> error for equals says data cannot be resolve is not a field?

Comment: @et remove the `data`, it should be `n.id()`